# GoogleMaps CancelableCallback will not change my Camera angle and position. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have added the camera positions and animate callback which are placed in my onMapReady().

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition =
               new CameraPosition.Builder()
                       .target(new LatLng(currentRoute.locations.get(1).getLatitude(),
                               currentRoute.locations.get(1).getLongitude()))
                       .tilt(60)
                       .bearing((float)currentRoute.getRouteEdges().getFirst().getHeading(currentRoute.getStart(), currentRoute.getFinish())-40)
                       .zoom(20)
                       .build();

       CameraUpdate update = (CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

       turnByTurnMap.animateCamera(update, new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {
           @Override
           public void onFinish() {
               if(currentPosition<currentRoute.locations.size()-1){
                   float bearing = HelperMethods.latLongToLocationDouble(currentRoute.locations.get(currentPosition).getLatitude(),
                           currentRoute.locations.get(currentPosition).getLongitude()).bearingTo(HelperMethods.latLongToLocationDouble(currentRoute.locations.get(currentPosition+1).getLatitude(),
  currentRoute.locations.get(currentPosition+1).getLongitude()));
                   CameraPosition cameraPosition =
                           new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                   .target(new LatLng(currentRoute.locations.get(currentPosition).getLatitude(),
                                           currentRoute.locations.get(currentPosition).getLongitude()))
                                   .tilt(60)
                                   .bearing(bearing)
                                   .zoom(20)
                                   .build();
                   currentPosition++;
               }
           }

           @Override
           public void onCancel() {

           }
       });
```

Why does the camera not move along the locations. There are 8 locations in the location array. Why does the camera not update?

EDIT:
I have added the animateCamera to the callback, however the callback is never called i have re-posted the current implementation, i have logged inside the call back and it never gets called?

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition =
                new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(new LatLng(currentRoute.locations.get(1).getLatitude(),
                                currentRoute.locations.get(1).getLongitude()))
                        .tilt(60)
                        .bearing((float)currentRoute.getRouteEdges().getFirst().getHeading(currentRoute.getStart(), currentRoute.getFinish())-40)
                        .zoom(20)
                        .build();

        CameraUpdate update = (CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        turnByTurnMap.animateCamera(update,
                3000,
                routeAnimationCancelableCallback);

        routeAnimationCancelableCallback = new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFinish: here");
                if(currentPosition<currentRoute.locations.size()-1){
                    float bearing = HelperMethods.latLongToLocationDouble(currentRoute.locations.get(currentPosition+1).getLatitude(),
                            currentRoute.locations.get(currentPosition+1).getLongitude()).bearingTo(HelperMethods.latLongToLocationDouble(currentRoute.locations.get(currentPosition+1).getLatitude(),
                            currentRoute.locations.get(currentPosition+2).getLongitude()));
                    CameraPosition cameraPosition =
                            new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                    .target(new LatLng(currentRoute.locations.get(currentPosition+1).getLatitude(),
                                            currentRoute.locations.get(currentPosition+1).getLongitude()))
                                    .tilt(60)
                                    .bearing(bearing)
                                    .zoom(10)
                                    .build();
                    CameraUpdate update = (CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                    turnByTurnMap.animateCamera(update,
                            3000,
                            routeAnimationCancelableCallback);
                    currentPosition++;
                }


            }
        };
```

Comment: In your `onFinish` you build the `cameraPosition` but don't actually do anything with it.

Comment: Thanks @Andy i have added the animate camera call, as correctly suggested. However the callback is still not called i have added the revised code, i hope someone can help. I have read the documentation many times and do not understand what i am missing? Thanks.

Comment: Another issue: when you call `animateCamera` initially you then immediately set `routeAnimationCancelableCallback` - this means the initial `animateCamera` knows nothing about your callback.  Simply move the initial `animateCamera` to after setting `routeAnimationCancelableCallback`.

Comment: @Andy Thanks that solved the issue, this was the answer. The animation now flows the first animation call had to come after the callback was created. If you want to post it as an answer i can flag it. If not i will do it myself later. Thanks Andy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In consideration of the second code post, simply move the initial call to `animateCamera` after the setting of `routeAnimationCancelableCallback`.  This also includes the initial fix to invoke `animateCamera` in the callback.

```
    // initial call to animateCamera was here...


    routeAnimationCancelableCallback = new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFinish: here");
            if(currentPosition<currentRoute.locations.size()-1){
                float bearing = HelperMethods.latLongToLocationDouble(currentRoute.locations.get(currentPosition+1).getLatitude(),
                        currentRoute.locations.get(currentPosition+1).getLongitude()).bearingTo(HelperMethods.latLongToLocationDouble(currentRoute.locations.get(currentPosition+1).getLatitude(),
                        currentRoute.locations.get(currentPosition+2).getLongitude()));
                CameraPosition cameraPosition =
                        new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                .target(new LatLng(currentRoute.locations.get(currentPosition+1).getLatitude(),
                                        currentRoute.locations.get(currentPosition+1).getLongitude()))
                                .tilt(60)
                                .bearing(bearing)
                                .zoom(10)
                                .build();
                CameraUpdate update = (CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                turnByTurnMap.animateCamera(update,
                        3000,
                        routeAnimationCancelableCallback);
                currentPosition++;
            }


        }
    };


    // and moved to here...

    turnByTurnMap.animateCamera(update,
            3000,
            routeAnimationCancelableCallback);
```